# Forcing time synchronisation on Windows 10 via W32TM

Tags: time, windows-10

I started to develop a new Windows 10 images for our WDS. I know we are a little late still running W7... but i have a problem concerning W32TM.

We had problems adding computers to the Domain after we deployed an image to a new computer because of a time difference. Lots of the new computers are sometimes days of. So before adding computer to the domain i batched a timesync. So I started W32Time service, added the locally time server and did a W32Time /resync /force.

On W10 the force does not work any more and I receive a message the time difference is to big. So i searched the Internet and found to edit the Register to increase the time limit from 54000 seconds to 4294967295 seconds. But i still receive the same Error message.

So i looked into the log and found some interesting. The Error ID is 34 and the text makes no sense. Well it is in German. Before i made the REG-Change the error message was:

Der Zeitdienst hat festgestellt, dass die Systemzeit um 82597 Sekunden geändert werden muss. Die Systemzeit kann durch den Zeitdienst um maximal 54000 Sekunden geändert werden.

So this is telling me the 82597 seconds are more than maximum of 54000 sec. Well this made sense, but after the Reg-Change it told me:

Der Zeitdienst hat festgestellt, dass die Systemzeit um 82597 Sekunden geändert werden muss. Die Systemzeit kann durch den Zeitdienst um maximal 4294967295 Sekunden geändert werden.

So the 82597 seconds won't fit into the 4294967295... I'm not that good in Mat, but eeehhhh.

Now even more strange. I started the Time and Date configuration app (or how it is called in English), set it to manually and changed the date to fit in the 15H/54000Sec. I switched back to automatically, and it switched back to yesterday.... Why? Time zone is correctly set to UTC+01:00

Next step: BIOS... edited Time and Date correctly in the bios, booted W10 and finally i could sync the time... using the GUI. But than i tested the script, and noticed it gives the same error and time and date went off 27 hours again. Even totally unlogical time i.a. now it is 12:13 and the time on the machine is yesterday 8:39. Hmm I did another restarts and BIOS-change to demonstrate this to my colleague and now the difference has changed. Time now 12:25 time on machine yesterday 8:29.

Also tested another Time server, same result. Now i am at the End of my wisdom an need some idea's from others.

Comment: 4294967295 is the unsigned 32 bit limit, so not _eeehhhh_ **but** FFFFFFFF.

Comment: That's not what i meant with eeehhhh. eeehhhh in this case is an expression like "D'oh" or "huh"? Maybe i should have quoted it, hmmmm.

Comment: yes, I know. However, just wanted to point out that may have obtained an overflow or alike